# How to move files from a dataframe into separate folders?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a covid dataset right now and I have loaded all the images into a dataframe.I have labelled covid positive images as 1 and normal images as zero.I want to separate the data into two folders namely 1 (*1 shall contain covid positive images*) and 0(*0 folder should contain normal images*).[Picture of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLa5O.png)

How can I do the same in google colab?

Comment: Where are the actual images stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go through the dataframe element by element and save to a folder based on the flag:

```
for file, flag in zip(df['filename'], df['categories']):
    if flag == 0:
        #save file to first directory
    elif flag == 1:
        #save file to second directory
```

Comment: Thank you. It gave me a fair idea of how to proceed and I could finally separate the images into different directories.